# Why do d3js tooltips disappear when using Leaflet version 1

Tags: css, d3.js, leaflet

I’ve been using d3js in combination with Leaflet, adding tooltips in a manner inspired by d3noob.

This worked when I was using an old version of Leaflet (0.7.3). When I tried the current version (Leaflet 1.0.3), I had to make a few changes:

- `L.svg().addTo(map)` instead of `map._initPathRoot()`
- `map.on("moveend", update)` instead of `map.on("viewreset", update)`
- set `pointer-events: visible` for circles.

However, the tooltips don’t show. As far as I can tell, they seem to work OK but get hidden behind the map tiles (for testing purposes I added some text and opacity 1 to the original tooltip element; it briefly appears in the top-left corner until the map tiles load). I tried adding a `z-index`, but this didn’t solve it.

- Here’s an [example](http://dirkmjk.nl/2017/windmolens/map_leaflet_0_7_3.html) that works, using Leaflet 0.7.3
- And here [one](http://dirkmjk.nl/2017/windmolens/map_leaflet_1_0_3.html) with Leaflet 1.0.3, where the tooltip disappears

Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label needs a higher z-index than your map, change the code below from 400 to 98 (99 is the value of the label)

```
.leaflet-pane {
    z-index: 98;
}
```